# Mostrar datos de un json en Angular

Tags: json, angular

Buenas tardes aqui mi problema tengo el siguiente  json que viene de una peticion

```
{"itinerary":"vamos a la playa"},{"itinerary":"despues al parque"},{"itinerary":"despues al mar"}
```

Necesito imprimirlo el contenido de cada item en una lista intente convirlo en JSON con `JSON.stringify(resp.Tour.whatsIncluded`

Pero no logro acceder a los indices

Gracias

Comment: agrega la llamada a la función que llama al json por favor

Comment: Fijate hacerlo sin JSON.stringify, esto se utiliza para pasar un json a string. Te recomiendo que prubes con JSON.parse() o en su defecto como recibis el mismo json

Answer (score 1):

Puedes intentar con JSON.parse(tuRespuesta) y almacenarlo. Ejemplo

```
miArray: any[] = [];
```

Si la respuesta de tu petición es un array (supongo que si) puedes hacer lo siguiente.

```
this.miArray = JSON.parse(tuRespuesta);
```

En tu html hacer un `*ngFor`

```
<tr *ngFor="let valor of miArray">
    <td>{{ valor.itinerary }}</td>
</tr>
```